# How to Store data from xml to php variable which is collection of data inside single tag like array

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, xml-parsing

I get Data as below in XML Format.

Now how to Store Values of  data like Description,CarMake,etc. Which is in between { } Brackets.

I want to Store Them Seperately in php.

```
<Vehicle xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://regcheck.org.uk">
<vehicleJson>
{ "Description": "JCB INDIA LIMITED / JCB 3DX", "RegistrationYear": "2010", "CarMake": { "CurrentTextValue": "JCB INDIA LIMITED" }, "CarModel": { "CurrentTextValue": "JCB 3DX" }, "MakeDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "JCB INDIA LIMITED" }, "ModelDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "JCB 3DX" }, "VechileIdentificationNumber": "1710000", "EngineNumber": "XXXXX", "FuelType": { "CurrentTextValue": "DIESEL" }, "RegistrationDate": "13/08/2010", "Owner": "RAMDEBHAI KARANGIYA", "Fitness": "18-Sep-2019", "Insurance": "05-Nov-2019", "Location": "RTO,PORBANDAR HIGHWAY", "ImageUrl": "http://in.carregistrationapi.com/image.aspx/@SkNCIElORElBIExJTUlURUQgLyBKQ0IgM0RY" }
</vehicleJson>
<vehicleData>
<Description>JCB INDIA LIMITED / JCB 3DX</Description>
<RegistrationYear>2010</RegistrationYear>
<CarMake>
<CurrentTextValue>JCB INDIA LIMITED</CurrentTextValue>
</CarMake>
<CarModel>JCB 3DX</CarModel>
</vehicleData>
</Vehicle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works. Create a php file and do the following code:

```
<?php

$xmlstr = <<<XML
<Vehicle xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://regcheck.org.uk">
<vehicleJson>
{ "Description": "JCB INDIA LIMITED / JCB 3DX", "RegistrationYear": "2010", "CarMake": { "CurrentTextValue": "JCB INDIA LIMITED" }, "CarModel": { "CurrentTextValue": "JCB 3DX" }, "MakeDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "JCB INDIA LIMITED" }, "ModelDescription": { "CurrentTextValue": "JCB 3DX" }, "VechileIdentificationNumber": "1710000", "EngineNumber": "XXXXX", "FuelType": { "CurrentTextValue": "DIESEL" }, "RegistrationDate": "13/08/2010", "Owner": "RAMDEBHAI KARANGIYA", "Fitness": "18-Sep-2019", "Insurance": "05-Nov-2019", "Location": "RTO,PORBANDAR HIGHWAY", "ImageUrl": "http://in.carregistrationapi.com/image.aspx/@SkNCIElORElBIExJTUlURUQgLyBKQ0IgM0RY" }
</vehicleJson>
<vehicleData>
<Description>JCB INDIA LIMITED / JCB 3DX</Description>
<RegistrationYear>2010</RegistrationYear>
<CarMake>
<CurrentTextValue>JCB INDIA LIMITED</CurrentTextValue>
</CarMake>
<CarModel>JCB 3DX</CarModel>
</vehicleData>
</Vehicle>
XML;

?>

<?php 
$Vehicle = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

echo "Description:" . $Vehicle->vehicleData->Description . '<br>';
echo "Registration Year: " . $Vehicle->vehicleData->RegistrationYear;
?>
```

As you can see it's doing what you want. Storing all of your XML data in a php variable which is `$xmlstr`. Then you store that variable inside another with the same name that your using which is `Vehicle`. Then you use simple php to get the data that you want! Let me know if it worked!

P.S - if you want to store each data separately in a different variable you can easily do:

```
$description = $Vehicle->vehicleData->Description;
echo "Description:" . $description . '<br>';
```